# error "too many values to unpack" while converting generator object to list

Tags: python, list, generator, raster, rasterio

I'm using rasterio sample module and I want to convert my output (generator) to list. I know that I can just use list() but it raises error "too many values to unpack (expected 2)". When I just use the sample module I get generator:

```
sample = rasterio.sample.sample_gen(raster, ['754707','4248548'])
```

but trying to make a list with:

```
sample = list(rasterio.sample.sample_gen(raster, ['754707','4248548']))
```

raises an error. I found .items() method but it works for dictionaries, it's not useful for generators, I'm working for the first time with a generator object and I don't get what is wrong.

Comment: The second param to `sample_gen` should be a list of pairs of x-y coords.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
sample = list(rasterio.sample.sample_gen(raster, [('754707','4248548')]))
```

In your example, the strings in your list are `Sequence`-like and iterable so when unpacking them, they get 6 values and it is expecting two values. Those strings might need be `int` or `float`, I'm not sure though